# Possible to step through/breakpoints as3 in flash buider when compiling with flash pro?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

As it says in the title, I have a project that is based in a Flash Professional .Fla 
However, I am doing all of the code writing and editing in Flash Builder. They are both set to have the same source path.

Although Flash Pro has the step through/ breakpoints functionality, it is not aware of breakpoints I add in from Flash Builder.

Since the project is meant to be compiled through the .fla I also can't simply compile with Flash Builder.

Does anyone have this workflow setup, and have you managed to put breakpoints in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I use the same setup almost all the time. How did you create your project?
I usually create the fla, then in FB I select new->flash pro project and point it to the fla file.

Now if I add a breakpoint in FB and I test the movie with ctrl(cmd)+shift+enter, the movie is published in Flash and is stopped at the first breakpoint.

Comment: The actual project in flash builder is huge and conatins our whole game. Many .fla's go into it. After the project is created is there a way to "point to" other .fla files?

Comment: Could you let us know your exact project setup? If you have them in the same project the breakpoints shouldn't be ignored. If you don't have them in a project, I doubt you could even set a breakpoint as FB would warn you and disable some features.

Comment: The code is all in an actionscript web project in flash builder. Some assets are in .swc files. Some are in the main .fla file. I am compiling from the main .fla file.